# How To Update One Mongo Documents Node.js based on string input?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have the async function below. `DeviceStatus` is a Mongo Collection of devices which has the property `SerialNumber` defined and `NumberOfRetries` defined. I want to take in as an input a `serialNumber` and `retries`. `serialNumber` is a string that is known to be in the collection. `retries` is a string representing an int less than 10. In the async function below I'd like to read the `retries` value, add 1 to it and then update the mongo document with the same `serialNumber`

```js
static async incrementNumberOfRetries(serialNumber, retries){
  const retriesInt = parseInt(retries);
  const accumulatedRetriesInt = retriesInt + 1;
  const accumulatedRetriesString = accumulatedRetriesInt.toString();
  try {
    await DeviceStatus
      .updateOne({
        "SerialNumber": serialNumber
        },
        {
          $set: {
            "NumberOfRetries" : accumulatedRetriesString
        }
      })
  } catch(error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
}
```

I'm not entirely sure what I'm doing wrong here. I know the first 3 lines are correct and there's no error being caught. But the `NumberOfRetries` is not being set properly in the collection. Initially, it's been set to 1 so I've tested this function and the value is not changing. Is there something wrong with how I'm using `updateOne`? How can I pass in a variable to perform the update?

Comment: `But the NumberOfRetries is not being set properly in the collection`. Could you please provide more information on this ? The value isn't changed?

Comment: Correct, the value is not updating. Currently, it's initialized as 0 so it's defined. It's just not incrementing.

Comment: So, is the field SerialNumber unique in your dataset? I mean, is there only 1 document for a SerialNumber? If there are more than 1, your query will update only the first document if finds from the database

Comment: SerialNumber is unique

Comment: I fixed it... The query is correct and works fine. I have a very similar collection where DeviceId is used instead of SerialNubmer. I had to be using DeviceId instead of SerialNubmer. Thanks, @ĐăngKhoaĐinh, for your responses. Upon further investigation everything is working now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To increment the `numberOfRetries`, you can use MongoDB update operator [`$inc`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/).

```js
DeviceStatus.update({
    serialNumber,
  },
  {
    $inc: {
      numberOfRetries: 1
  }
})
```

See a working example here on [MongoDb Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/SqWH9BL-5NJ)

Your code should look like this

```js
static async incrementNumberOfRetries(serialNumber, retries){
  try {
    await DeviceStatus
      .update({
        "SerialNumber": serialNumber
        },
        {
          $inc: {
            "NumberOfRetries" : 1
        }
      })
  } catch(error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
}
```

Check out the docs for the [$inc operator here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/)